# Twitter Ads API Access

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to access Twitter Ads API. I have created a developer account and created an App with all permissions. But, when I try to access the API, I am getting the following error:

> The client application making this request does not have access to Twitter Ads API

I checked and found that after creating a developer account, I need to apply for Ads API access. I found the following link from their official documentation and forum:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/apply

But, this is not working anymore.

Here, https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/getting-started, they say:

> Request access to the Ads API by reaching out to your Twitter representative.

I am not sure whom to contact for this. How to find out Twitter representative?

Can someone please help me to get Ads API Access?